# Payweek calculation ending each Sunday

Tags: excel

I am using the following formula to find week ends of Sunday.

```
=CEILING.MATH(A5,7)+1
```

I had to add the "+1" because I was getting Saturday.  The problem happens on the final Sunday which should have the same pay week but instead it iterates to the following Sunday.

12 October is resulting in 19 October Payweek.  It should be the end payweek.

Comment: Can you provide a list of inputs for `A5` and the desired results of the formula. That will help decipher what we are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

## Formula:

`=A5+(7-WEEKDAY(A5,2))`

This formula will convert any date into the date of the following Sunday with Sunday returning itself even spanning years and Months.

Comment: Yes that does what I need.  Sorry that I am not allowed to post screen shots - that was my intention.

Comment: If it works, please mark it as the answer to inform future visitors.